# Locate all geocodable addresses on a track using Google Maps JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps JavaScript API. Is it possible to locate the houses (geocodable address) on a track? Currently I draw a track using the list latitude and longitude points. I don't want to upload the house locations in fusion tables. It should be able to detect a house from Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the web service:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&sensor=false
```

It gives you the address of the given position.

You can find the complete documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro).

Comment: Thanks! But I need to find all the houses "on a line". So, lets say I draw a line on the map using start and end coordinates, Then I need to mark all the houses that are on this line.